# Getting custom error message from backend using ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, error-handling

I have a register form that submits and saves the form data into a mongo database with no problems. However, when there is an error with the form I want the backend script to send back a string identifying the problem i.e. "all fields required", or "passwords don't match". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I can't seem to access that string from the front end.

This is my backend in node js. If you submit an empty form the error message "All fields required" is outputted to the backend console as expected. But I can't access it from the front end.

```
router.post("/register", function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.body.email &&
    req.body.username &&
    req.body.password &&
    req.body.confirmPassword) {

      // confirm that user typed same password twice
      if (req.body.password !== req.body.confirmPassword) {
        var err = new Error("Passwords do not match.");
        err.status = 400;
        return next(err);
      }

      // create object with form input
      var userData = {
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
      };

      User.create(userData, function (error, user) {
        if (error) {
          return next(error);
        } else {
          req.session.userId = user._id;
          req.session.username = user.username;
          return res.redirect(`/profile/${user.username}`);
        }
      });

    } else {
        var err = new Error("All fields required");
        err.status = 400;
        console.log("Error " + JSON.stringify(err)); // THis is ok
        return next(err); // This doesn't seem to be working properly
    }
})
```

This is my front end ajax post to the server.

```
    $("#register-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize(),
                })
        .done(function(){
            alert("Done");
        })
        .fail(function(a, b, c) {
            console.log("a " + typeof a + " " + a + " " + JSON.stringify(a));
            console.log("b " + typeof b + " " + b);
            console.log("c " + typeof c + " " + c);
        })
    });
```

Front end console output is:

```
a object [object Object] {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
b string error
c string
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my backend `else` clause which handles the error to

```
else {
        res.send(400, 'All fields required');
    }
```

It works.